# PHP not sending email from html

Tags: php, html, email, post, web

I'm trying to make a form where the user introduces data and it gets submitted to e-mail.

However, it gets me to a blank page (file.php page), and the e-mail is not sent.

HTML code:

```
<form action="./sendmail.php" method="post">
    <div class="log">
        <input type="text" id="name" value="name" name="studname" class="form">
        <input type="email" id="mail" value="mail@gmail.com" name="studmail" class="form">
        <input type="tel" id="age" value="age" class="form" name="studage">
        <input type="submit" value="submit!" id="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

And now here is my "sendmail.php" code:

```
<?php
    /*  STUDENT PARAMETERS  */
    $studentName = $_POST['studname'];
    $studentMail = $_POST['studmail'];
    $studentAge = $_POST['studage'];

    mail('code@gmail.com', 'Message',
    'NAME: ' . $studentName . '\nMAIL: ' . $studentMail . '\nAge: ' . $studentAge);
?>
```

How can I solve this and why is this not working? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I believe you need `..` before the forward slash in `action` if you want to specify everything preceding it. And also you need to use periods to concatenate strings in PHP.

Comment: onetrickpony is correct, use . to concatenate strings, not + - that is your first problem...

Comment: sorry, my bad, but still not receiving the emails. I've changed + for . and the script is being accessed by the html file because it goes to the php script page. But is not sending the e-mail for some reason

Comment: Maybe there are other errors as well, which could be a configuration problem, or just a syntax error in your script. Please look-up sources about how to get feedback from PHP. You can enable error reporting to see syntax errors. The mail function itself doesn't return much information, but it returns at least a boolean to indicate success.

Comment: try `echo mail(....)` see if it actually sends. Maybe turn on errors too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use phpmailer class

Answer (score 0):

@Telmo Vaz try this

```
<?php
    $studentName = $_POST['studname'];
        $studentMail = $_POST['studmail'];
        $studentAge = $_POST['studage'];

    $recipient='code@gmail.com'; 
    $subject="Message"; 
    $content = "New Message Form Contact us\n From: ".$studentName .", \n Email: ".$studentMail .",\n Age: ".$studentAge;
        $headers = 'From: code@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: code@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        $retval=mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $headers);
        if( $retval == true ){do something;}
        else{echo "Error Sending Message";}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need an email address to send the email from. The email won't be send from this address, but the selected address will be shown in the "From" section. Try this:

```
/*  STUDENT PARAMETERS  */
$studentName = $_POST['studname'];
$studentMail = $_POST['studmail'];
$studentAge = $_POST['studage'];

$to = "code@gmail.com";
$subject = "Message";
$message = "NAME: " . $studentName . "\nMAIL: " . $studentMail . "\nAge: " . $studentAge;
$from = $to;
$headers = "From:" . $from;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

echo "Mail Sent.";
```

Comment: It should send even without `$headers`. It just uses default values.

Comment: @putvande Yes, I think so, but that's a matter if taste.